# Pandas : fill with 0 some categorical data

Tags: python, pandas, categorical-data

I have a dataset with dates (this could potentially be anything but categorical data), and I want to count the number of occurence by day of week (and/or by month or year, with the same logic).

I have something like this, for the day of week (in french...) :

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# this is simulation, of course my datas are more complex ;-)
data = {'date': ["2000-01-01", "2000-05-01", "2000-11-11", "2000-11-01"], 'col_2': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

# date conversion
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df['day_of_week'] = df['date'].dt.day_name(locale = 'fr_FR')

# group by
data = df.groupby('day_of_week')['day_of_week'].agg(['count'])
data.reset_index(level=0, inplace=True)

# order by... order of the day in the week
JOUR_SEMAINE = ["Lundi", "Mardi", "Mercredi", "Jeudi", "Vendredi", "Samedi", "Dimanche"]
MAPPING_SEMAINE = {day: i for i, day in enumerate(JOUR_SEMAINE)}

key = data['day_of_week'].map(MAPPING_SEMAINE)
data = data.iloc[key.argsort()]

# see
data
```

| . | day_of_week | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Lundi | 1 |
| 1 | Mercredi | 1 |
| 2 | Samedi | 2 |

This is nice, but how can i fill absent days with 0, to obtain this:

| . | day_of_week | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Lundi | 1 |
| 1 | Mardi | 0 |
| 3 | Mercredi | 1 |
| 4 | Jeudi | 0 |
| 5 | Vendredi | 0 |
| 6 | Samedi | 2 |
| 7 | Dimanche | 0 |

**To be more generic**, i'm searching the more automatic way to have one value for each index of my categorical array (in this case JOUR_SEMAINE), either the calculated value (count) or 0...

Does anyone have a clue?

Thank's in advance

Comment: try use df.fillna(0) to replace nan value with 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would create the categorical data frame. We can get the week-day names using the calendar library.

```py
import pandas as pd
import calendar as cal

weekdays = [wd for wd in cal.day_name]
weekday_count_df = pd.DataFrame(index=weekdays)
weekday_count_df
```

Next, we put your data into a data frame.

```py
data = {'date': ["2000-01-01", "2000-05-01", "2000-11-11", "2000-11-01"], 'col_2': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']}
data_df = pd.DataFrame(data)
data_df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(data_df['date'])
data_df['day_of_week'] = data_df['date'].dt.day_name()
data_df
```

Next, we can join the two data frames.

```py
data_group_df = data_df.groupby('day_of_week')['date'].count()
weekday_count_df = weekday_count_df.join(data_group_df)
weekday_count_df = weekday_count_df.fillna(0)
weekday_count_df
```

Finally, we can fix the column type and name.

```py
weekday_count_df = weekday_count_df.rename(columns={'date':'count'})
weekday_count_df['count'] = weekday_count_df['count'].astype('int32')
weekday_count_df
```

The final result would be this:

```
            count
Monday      1
Tuesday     0
Wednesday   1
Thursday    0
Friday      0
Saturday    2
Sunday      0
```

Comment: join the data frames.. _Just one word: **sublime**_!
Many thank's